# Applying $\ell_1$-norm heuristic to this cardinality optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have the following optimization problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{min} && \mathop{\textrm{card}}(x_+)\\
& \text{s.t.} && Ax = b
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\mathop{\textrm{card}}(\cdot)$ is the $\ell_0$-norm (cardinality) and $x_+$ is element-wise positive ($x_+ = \max\{0, x\}$). $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ where $m < n$.

I know this is a cardinality optimization and in general it's hard to solve.

I searched for heuristics for solving cardinality optimization and found [this lecture slides](http://www.ece.ust.hk/~palomar/ELEC5470_lectures/13/slides_sparsity_cvx_optim.pdf). From page 9 I see that we can apply $\ell_1$-norm heuristic to this kind of problem, but I don't understand how exactly should I do that for my specific problem.

Comment: <soapbox> please do not use the faulty and deceiving notation $\|\cdot\|_0$. The cardinality function is not a norm, and I have seen a lot of evidence that its casual use has led people to falsely believe it is convex. Use $\mathop{\textrm{card}}(\cdot)$ (LaTeX: `\mathop{\textrm{card}}(\cdot)`)  instead. </soapbox>

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thank you for the suggestion and the question has been edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $x_+$ is nonnegative, the $\ell_1$ approximation to cardinality just reduces to the straight elementwise sum. So you need:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \sum_i \max\{x_i,0\} \\
\text{subject to} & A x = b
\end{array}
This is easily converted to a linear program by introducing a new variable $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \sum_i y_i \\
\text{subject to} & A x = b \\
                  & y \succeq x \\
                  & y \succeq 0
\end{array}
Of course, this is a heuristic, so do not expect it to reliably produce the minimum cardinality solution without some sort of a priori knowledge about $A$ (e.g., the RIP property).